# How to Change the click listener position on grid view images?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

[image]

I am using the below material design for my [android app](http://www.techinfoworld.com), in my app i also include the navigation drawer on new version 23 , in this grid view each image i click this to open new activity page,.

But in my app, i will not be opened , if i clicked left side above part section only the respective activity will be opened ,

Shall i know how to change the position for the click on my grid view image correctly ,

Please help me to solve my issue ,

Please check the image for clarification !!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: click to open new activity for each images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ClickListener inside adapter

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    gridView =new View(mContext);

    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_members, null);

    Button city = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.city);

                city.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    //Toast here

        }});

    return gridView;
}
```

Hopefully above code will help you